# Issue activating a generic type with generic array in constructor parameters

Tags: generics, reflection, activator

I have a very strange issue with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testTuples1 = GimeStringTuples("foo", "bar");
            var testTuples2 = GimeTuples("foo", "bar");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static object GimeStringTuples(params string[] values)
        {
            Type genericType = Type.GetType("System.Tuple`" + values.Length);
            Type[] typeArgs = values.Select(_ => typeof(string)).ToArray();
            Type specificType = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
            return Activator.CreateInstance(specificType, values);
        }

        public static object GimeTuples<T>(params T[] values)
        {
            Type genericType = Type.GetType("System.Tuple`" + values.Length);
            Type[] typeArgs = values.Select(_ => typeof(T)).ToArray();
            Type specificType = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

            dynamic result;
            string[] testArgs = { "foo", "bar" };
            result = Activator.CreateInstance(specificType, testArgs);
            result = Activator.CreateInstance(specificType, values);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

It's failing on the second to last line:

```
result = Activator.CreateInstance(specificType, values);
```

This is weird since it's basically identical to the line that executes just before it:

```
result = Activator.CreateInstance(specificType, testArgs);
```

In both cases, the same argument is being passed as the `specificType` parameter and a `string[2]` is being passed as the second parameter.

And the `GimeStringTuples` method works just fine... although there are no generics involved there - which is maybe the hint.

Can anyone explain this unusual behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you what happens. Having a look at the resulting assembly you can see that the compiler introduces an `object[]` wrapping the `values` argument:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(specificType, new string[] { "foo", "bar" });
Activator.CreateInstance(specificType, new object[] { values });
```

Now the right overload can not be found anymore.
If you add a cast you will get the expected result and the code works again:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(specificType, values as string[])
```

But i can not tell you why this happens, maybe it can be digged out of the specs.

Comment: Thanks @thehennyy... that gives me enough to go on. It can be avoided by casting the value array to an object[] in the first place. This seems to be a subtlety of how the compiler treats generic arrays when passing them as parameters to a method with a params signature... it passes the whole array as a single argument rather than passing each element of the array. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

OK so the solution (thanks to @thehennyy):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testTuple = GimeTuples("foo", "bar");
            Console.WriteLine(testTuple);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static object GimeTuples<T>(params T[] values)
        {
            Type genericType = Type.GetType("System.Tuple`" + values.Length);
            Type[] typeArgs = values.Select(_ => typeof(T)).ToArray();
            Type specificType = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
            object[] constructorArguments = values.Cast<object>().ToArray();
            return Activator.CreateInstance(specificType, constructorArguments);
        }
    }
}
```

This forces the compiler to pass the generic array elements as params rather than passing the whole array as a single param.